# Browser automatically adds <a>-Tag without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, hyperlink, inspector

I just ran into a problem on a bit bigger site than in the example below which caused me to investigate for several hours until I found the cause of the bug. My problem was, that the Browser automatically spawned `<a>`-Tags for no reason.

Let's say I've some HTML code that looks like this:

```
<a href="#">Link<a/>
<!-- Some code-magic; after a while you have something like: -->
<div>Not a link</div>
```

Of course the problem is pretty obvious in this case. But if the page is a bit more complex and you don't notice the wrong close of the `<a>`-Tag above, you're gonna have a bad time.

Why? Well, that's easy to show. You might expect that everything that follows is clickable. That is by fact true. But - and that's a thing that I did not know - the browser adds `<a>`-Tags after the page is loaded. Which means, in the inspector (tested in Chrome and Firefox) you'll find something like this:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a>
    <!-- Some code-magic; after a while you have something like: -->
    <div>Not a link</div>
</a>
```

Interesting, huh? The browser closes the `<a>`-Tag properly on the first line and opens a new one around the div. You might can guess that I've started debugging all JavaScripts on the page (an there were many) because I thought JavaScript is the only thing that changes the code after the page was fetched from the server.

Well, now I know, it's not the only thing. While trying to debug this problem I haven't found any information on the internet about it so I thought I'll share my knowledge with the guy having the exact same problem in the future (and we all know: He'll be there soon).

But, there is still one unanswered question: Why? I can't see a reason why the Browser should autofix this and create new tags. That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Only explanation I have for this is that parsing happens in two steps. First some sort of "tag soup" mode, where the browser tries to just close everything that gets open. Afterwards (when the site is done loading)the parser tokenizes the (X)HTML and discovers that mis-typed closing tag. It assumes that was meant to be </a> and fixes that. At the end of the document it discovers the </a> it inserted in the first step. And tries to add the opening tag. Of course this is all speculation... But it's the only explanation I can come up with right now. Do other browsers (IE, Opera, ...) do the same?

Comment: Well I'd guess it's related to why browsers automatically create `<tbody>` tags in tables. It just already knows, if there is no `<thead>`, the website author intends to use `<tbody>`. I can't tell for sure, but I'd say specifications of HTML do not allot an `<a>` tag within an `<a>` tag, what purpose would that serve? So once the self-closing `<a/>` appeared, it ended the unclosed one and started a new one. Though since `<a>` is meant to be a container, it can't be self-terminating. I don't know why though it would end with the next tag. This would require a lot of inquiries...

Comment: Good find. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual question should be, why would you intentionally feed the browser with invalid HTML?

But back on-topic. Historically, HTML has been a jerky markup language. People without notion of DOM would write HTML such as:

```
<B><U>hi, </B> shall I be underlined or not?</U>
```

The above is clearly invalid HTML. However, the browser won't vomit if you feed it with invalid HTML. It will attempt to recover the document in the way it *thinks* the author intended.

Elements in the DOM (which is what the inspector shows you) can only have one parent element. So logically, the `<U>` must be closed before `<B>` is closed. But `<U>` hasn't been closed by the author, so the browser assumes the rest of the text shall too be underlined. Hence, the invalid HTML is recovered to approximately the following DOM structure:

```
<B><U>hi, </U></B><U> shall I be underlined or not?</U>
```

---

And in your specific case, `<a>` tags cannot be self-closed in HTML, so:

```
<a>...<a/>
```

The `/` is interpreted as syntactic sugar and the browser thinks you've opened a second `<a>` element without closing the first. It will most likely spawn the anchor element through the whole document until encountering the necessary closing `</a>`'s in the recover process.

Comment: I wouldn't say self-closing tags do not exist in HTML. Because then, `<br />`, `<link />`, `<meta />`, etc, would be invalid XML, being unclosed containers... But as long as it's not XHTML, I guess you could say it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Derija93 Yes, those are necessary in XHTML/XML, what I meant is that specifically for HTML parsers the `/` only serves as syntactic sugar/cross-compatibility with XHTML.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - FWIW, there are some situations where normal HTML parsers (i.e. not XHTML) will treat `<foo>` as a start tag (i.e. it requires an `</foo>` tag to end the element) and `<foo />` as a self-closing tag. But an `<a />` tag is never one of them, so your answer is fine on that point.

Comment: @Alohci Not sure if I understood your point. Did you mean closing tag omission rules? Many tags must have closing tags (`<div>`, `<script>`), others are not allowed to have a closing tag (`<link>`, `<meta>`) and some, under certain circumstances, have optional closing tags (`<li>`,  `<option>`, `<p>`, `<dd>`). But, if you meant that `<foo>` and `<foo />` can have different meaning in an HTML context, I'd love to see a live example. It'd be enlightening.

Comment: There's actually two cases. One where the meaning is different, and one which is just a browser quirk. For the former, in HTML5, tags for elements in foreign namespaces can self-close. So for example, `<math>` means start the math element, while `<math />` means start and end the math element. The latter situation occurs only in IE <= 8 browsers with the HTML5 shiv. In this case, the new elements e.g `section` are treated as truly self closing when written as `<section />`

Comment: @Alohci Thanks, I haven't read the MathML spec yet. Also, foreign elements can be marked as self-closing in HTML5 (heh, talking about `<foo />` all this time and I just reminded of that). I've fixed the misleading statement in the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. `<a/>` may be interpreted as an attempt for a self-closing anchor tag, so in fact a new anchor
2. Nested anchors are illegal, so the browser closes the first one before opening the second.

However, I have no proof of that, it's pretty much a guess.

---

*More speculations:* It is probably a browser-dependent behavior and related to why browsers automatically create `<tbody>` tags in tables. They just already know, if there is no `<thead>`, the website author intends to use `<tbody>`.

So once the self-closing `<a/>` appeared, it ended the unclosed anchor and started a new one. Though since `<a>` is meant to be a container, it can't be self-terminating. The anchor would then end according to XHTML rules, i.e. closing the contained tags before the containers.

This would require a lot of inquiries on both the HTML specifications and individual browser behavior.

Comment: Should've written my guess as an answer... that said, since we have the same reasoning: +1

Comment: Yes, I've seen your guess right after posting this. I'm making this answer community wiki, feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like a logic answer for this case. You're awesome!