# <a> tag always inserts after <div> tag

Tags: html, css

I have been creating a [GitHub project called AnyMath](https://github.com/Pegladon/All-You-Can-Math/tree/peg's-dev) using HTML, CSS and JS, and recently I struck a bit of a roadblock. In my index.html file, everything seems fine and normal, but when I run my program, issues occur and the chrome inspector shows that an `<a href="#" class="link-unmade"></a>` tag is inserted in several spots (I think this tag is inserted after `<div>` tags).

This by itself doesn't cause many problems as the `<a>` tag is empty, but I am using a responsive grid, and the `row:first-child { margin-left: 0; }` is not applying to my first colum as the first child is the `<a href="#" class="link-unmade"></a>` tag. So, my grid isn't working properly, and I don't really want to try to ignore or jerry rig a fix to make my grids work as it may only lead to more problems later.

The following is a screenshot trying to explain what is occuring using the chrome inspector (These  tags only show up when I run the code)
[Image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/M69Y4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M69Y4.png).

If you can offer any help that would be great, and I encourage those that are wanting to help to check out the GitHub project under peg's dev tree (link at top) and check the code. Thanks, and I hope you can help me.

Comment: what exactly layout should be like?

Comment: The first column of the row (the left most column) should have zero margin, this way all three columns stay evenly spread in the row and fit properly. However, the `<a>` element that is being inserted for whatever reason after the `<div class="row">` tag, is the first child of the row, and so the `margin-left: 0;` is being applied to it instead of the first column.

Comment: Make sure that you used **valid** HTML and closed all `<a>` tags. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737837/browser-automatically-adds-a-tag-without-javascript

Comment: yeah that worked, post that as an answer and I will set it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **invalid** or **bad** HTML is written, the browser instead of giving an error tries to make sense out of it.
In your code `<a>` were not closed properly so the browser appends new `<a>` tags. Thus you get to see new `<a>` tags at **runtime** while you won't see them in your source code.